# Remove single quotes/quotation marks in Prolog

Tags: string, prolog, swi-prolog, quotation-marks, single-quotes

I have an extern API sending info to my Prolog application and I found a problem creating my facts.

When the information received is extensive, Prolog automatically adds `'` (single quotes) to that info.

Example: with the data received, the fact I create is:

```
object(ObjectID,ObjectName,'[(1,09:00,12:00),(2,10:00,12:00)]',anotherID)
```

The fact I would like to create is

```
object(ObjectID,ObjectName,[(1,09:00,12:00),(2,10:00,12:00)] ,anotherID)
```

without the `'` before the list.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? With a predicate that receives `'[(1,09:00,12:00),(2,10:00,12:00)]'` and returns `[(1,09:00,12:00),(2,10:00,12:00)]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is an *atom*, and you want to convert it to a *term* I think.

If you use [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), you can use the builtin [`term_to_atom/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_to_atom/2):

> True if `Atom` describes a term that unifies with `Term`. When `Atom` is instantiated, `Atom` is parsed and the result unified with `Term`.

**Example:**

```
?- term_to_atom(X,'[(1,09:00,12:00),(2,10:00,12:00)]').
X = [ (1, 9:0, 12:0), (2, 10:0, 12:0)].
```

So at the right hand side, you enter the *atom*, at the left side the "*equivalent*" term. Mind however that for instance `00` is interpreted as a number and thus is equal to `0`, this can be unintended behavior.

You can thus translate the predicate as:

```
translate(object(A,B,C,D),object(A,B,CT,D)) :-
    term_to_atom(CT,C).
```

Since you do not fully specify how you get this data, it is unknown to me how you will convert it. But the above way will probably be of some help.